# edit the html file with powershell - remove column

Tags: html, powershell

I have report the get all info that I need from my VC on VMware ( I have 5 VCs)
the report show all in one table like
vmname, notes, username , vc1.john.com
(Depends on where the machine is associated) I exported to CSV and HTML file and everting its work fine

but I need to change 2 tings

1. remove the Vcenter (FQDN) from column and put tital on each Table in one HTML file
2. I want to translate the VC FQDN on the tital

like this

VC prod
vmname, notes, username

VC test
vmname, notes, username

thanks guys

the part of my scripts

ConvertTo-Html -Property VM,','Folder name', 'vCenter' | out-file $FileHtml

---

ok
this is my script
$Vcenter = 'vc1' ,'vc2',"vc3",'vc4' , 'vc5'

Connect-VIServer -Server $Vcenter  -Protocol https -User $psUsername  -Password $psPassword -Force

$excelfile = "D:\scripts\Report_VMs.csv"

$FileHtml = "D:\scripts\VMs.html"

$caNames = 'Backup'

$report = Get-VM| Where-Object { $_.PowerState -eq "PoweredOff"

$report |ForEach-Object -Process {

```
    $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property (

        [ordered]@{

             VM               = $_.Name

            'attribute value2' = ''

             Notes            = $_.Notes

            'attribute value2' = ''

            'attribute value3' = ''

            "Folder name"     = $_.Folder.Name

            'Last Backup'     = ''

             vCenter           = ([uri]$_.ExtensionData.Client.ServiceUrl).Host

        }

    )

    Get-Annotation -Entity $_ -CustomAttribute $caNames -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |

    ForEach-Object -Process {

            $obj."$($_.Name)" = $_.Value

    }

    $obj

} |
```

Export-Csv $excelfile -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture -Encoding UTF8

now... I need to take each vCenter from the table column and do rename like
instead of vc1.daniel.com like vc _prod
next put Title for each table the name of the VC - like VC prod
and and if it is possible to remove the VC column from the table - because it is no longer relevant

please fix my script
thanks

Comment: the post is edit my question
like this

VC prod (titel)
vmname, notes, username

VC test   (titel)
vmname, notes, username



the part of my scripts

Comment: Are you converting a PS table?  If so modify the table before converting to HTML.

Comment: Please explain what the input data is (probably a PsCustomObject array). Also please show us examples of what the table now looks like and what your desired output should be. It is also not clear to me (without example) what you intend to do with _"translate the VC FQDN on the titel"_

Comment: Please [edit] the question when adding more details. Answers are for answering the question, not for providing more details.